# 20 inch wheel HOLLOW HUB

Tags: wheels, identify-this-bike, hub

I have a 20 inch wheel with 28 spokes.

The hub has no bearings but a slot in it to accept a pin in axle.

As the axle turns, pin keeps wheel from slipping on axle.

Who made it, no one knows.  I have contacted several bicycle wheel makers.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Could you post a picture?

Comment: @WeiwenNg I think its an Identify-this-bike question, but just for the weird wheel.  I've never heard of a bicycle wheel held to an axle with pins (presumably cotter pins) sounds more like a wheelbarrow or trolley.   A photo will help a lot.

Comment: I have a tricycle in my garage with a differential. The hubs look like cups with a hole in the thick bottom of the cup for the axle, and with a slot for a pin. It could be something like this?

Comment: Photos might help, and if you're looking to replace it, some idea of what it works with.  It's possibly a repurposed wheelchair part